# Is there an ansible conditional or fact to check if the host can successfully login to another server with SSH?

Tags: ssh, ansible

I need to check if the host can successfully login to another server with SSH.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "has access"? If the host can connect to port 22 of the other host or if you actually can login, for example with ssh key forwarding?

Comment: I mean authrorised to login to the server with ssh

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing. If you think about it, it would be impossible to do that with built-in facts or other mechanisms. How should Ansible know about the other host(s), what username, authentication method etc to use... Also it would be a waste if Ansible would try to make each host connect to just every other host it knows about.

You will need to write a task and save the output for further use. But that should actually be quite easy.

```
- shell: ssh other.host echo awesome that works
  failed_when: false
  register: ssh_test
```

Then you can use that output in any other task as a condition:

```
- foo: bar
  when: "'awesome that works' in ssh_test.stdout_lines"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no fact for this, but you can use the ping module. http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ping_module.html

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the answer provided by @smiller171, here is a play that will test SSH (or other inventory configured communication) connectivity from target1 -> target2.  The status variable will contain information you can use to determine if connectivity failed

```
- hosts: target2
  tasks:

  - ping:
    delegate_to: target1
    register: status
    ignore_errors: yes

  - debug: msg="target1 failed to communicated with target2"
    when: status | failed
```